# Как читать файл через определённое количество строк?

Tags: python

Есть файл состоящий из нескольких тысяч, а то и сотен тысяч строк. В дальнейшем он выводится графиком. Чтобы сделать превьюшку, хочу выводить по оси X не каждую точку, а через, скажем через десять или сто. Вопрос: как читать не весь файл, а через определённое количество строк?

Comment: по сути, все равно весь файл придется читать. если не хотите памяти много использовать читайте построчно, оставляйте только нужные данные

Comment: Строки разной длины?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вопрос не в том, чтобы не читать весь файл, а в том, чтобы обрабатывать, скажем, каждую 10?

Comment: Да, чтобы в time_interval=[]
y1=[]
y2=[]
y3=[] попадала на каждая строка.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
# enumerate для каждого элемента возвращает еще и его индекс
for index, x in enumerate(lines):
    # если остаток от деления не 0, то index не кратен 10 - пропускаем
    if index % 10 != 0: 
         continue
    time_interval.append(x.split(' ')[0])# split(',') 
    y1.append(x.split(' ')[1])
    y2.append(x.split(' ')[2])
    y3.append(x.split(' ')[3])
```

Второй способ:

```
for x in lines[0::10]:
    time_interval.append(x.split(' ')[0])# split(',') 
    y1.append(x.split(' ')[1])
    y2.append(x.split(' ')[2])
    y3.append(x.split(' ')[3])
```

Тут `lines[0::10]` возвращает список из каждого 10-го элемента `lines`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё работает как надо!

Comment: Оба способа работают, но второй мне как-то "ближе")

Comment: Попробовал вот так: lines=f.readlines()[0::100] ... Тоже работает! Кстати, до это нужно было пропустить первые 10 строк делал так: lines=f.readlines()[10:] # пропустить первые 10 строк.

Answer (score -2):

Как бы это нужно, чтобы оставалась каждая десятая или сотая или ещё какая строка. Сечас я делаю так:

```
f=open("VOLT.txt",newline='\n')
lines=f.readlines()
time_interval=[]
y1=[]
y2=[]
y3=[]
for x in lines:
    time_interval.append(x.split(' ')[0])# split(',') 
    y1.append(x.split(' ')[1])
    y2.append(x.split(' ')[2])
    y3.append(x.split(' ')[3])
f.close()
...
...
...
plt.show()
```

Получается очень подробный график. Но он такой не всегда нужен. Нужно бывает посмотреть общие очертания.

Comment: для уточнения вопроса - отредактируйте именно вопрос, а не создавайте ответ.